# Angular does not bind data immediately even when value is hardcoded

Tags: javascript, html, angular, aframe

I am attempting to integrate A-Frame into Angular html template, but I do not fully understand how Angular handles data binding. A-Frame library is imported in the `polyfills.ts`.

Given the template:

```
<a-asset-item
  [attr.id]="'cityModel'"
  [attr.src]="'https://cdn.aframe.io/test-models/models/glTF-2.0/virtualcity/VC.gltf'"
  (error)="error($event)"
  (loaded)="assetItemLoaded($event)">
</a-asset-item>
```

Angular will first populate the dom with:

```
<a-asset-item></a-asset-item>
```

None of the data-bindings are bound *yet*. A-Frame proceeds to attempt to read from `<a-asset-item>` for the `id` and `src`, but because they are not yet bound (even though they are hard-coded in this example) they will cause a null error.

```
Cannot read lastIdexOf null
```

If we ignore this error, we will next see that both `id` and `src` are assigned in the DOM, just not at the same time as when `<a-asset-item>` was created.

```
<a-asset id="cityModel" src="https://cdn.aframe.io/test-models/models/glTF-2.0/virtualcity/VC.gltf">
```

This results in a race. A-Frame is eager to read from `a-asset-item` as soon as it appears on the DOM. Angular is eager to append the element to the DOM without populating all its attributes.

Is there a way to append the element and it's attributes at the same time into the DOM, while keeping the benefits of data-binding?

---

Additional update:

I was able to overcome the non-immediate binding issue with:

```
<a-asset-item
  id=""
  src=""
  [attr.id]="'cityModel'"
  [attr.src]="'https://cdn.aframe.io/test-models/models/glTF-2.0/virtualcity/VC.gltf'"
  (error)="error($event)"
  (loaded)="assetItemLoaded($event)">
</a-asset-item>
```

Same time as element:

```
id=""
src=""
```

After element:

```
[attr.id]="'cityModel'"
[attr.src]="'https://cdn.aframe.io/test-models/models/glTF-2.0/virtualcity/VC.gltf'"
```

Comment: I am not too sure what is happening in your code, tried to follow but you know how that can go. First thought, have you tried just using a simple if condition in the template to prevent the null errors.

Comment: Does this run properly locally? Check your networks tab , maybe external loading is causing it to delay? Try with offline resources, or try throttling your network in chrome dev tools (network throttling) and see if the delay increases

Comment: I get the same error if I were to do `[attr.src]="''"`, empty string works here `src=""`. The issue is that `src` doesn't exist alongside `a-asset-item` simultaneously when the element is first rendered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be a non-issue if I directly modify the A-Frame source code:

*Angular:*

```
<a-asset-item
  *ngFor="let model of assetItems; trackBy: trackAsset"
  [attr.id]="model?.id"
  [attr.src]="model?.asset?.file?.uri">
</a-asset-item>
```

*aframe-v0.9.2.js:*

```
registerElement('a-asset-item', {
  prototype: Object.create(ANode.prototype, {
    createdCallback: {
      value: function () {
        ...
      }
    },

    attachedCallback: {
      value: function () {
        var self = this;
        var src = this.getAttribute('src') || ''; // <--- Modified line
        ...
      }
    }
  })
});
```

This way, even though Angular is initially missing src before data-binding, the app does not error out. Src can still be updated and bound without issue.